# Sometimes scripts idle and require me to press RETURN in order to unlock them - Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, windows, django

this has been happening quite a few times, and have not been able to explain this behaviour in any way.

Often I write quick Python scripts for some quick tasks, often these tasks are row iterations using Django's ORM.

example:

```
from core.models import MyModel

ITEM_IDS = [...]

for index, item_id in enumerate(ITEM_IDS):
    print index
    if MyModel.objects.filter(serial=item_id).count():
        do_something()
        print index, item_id
```

**at times the script stops on one of the iterations indefinitely,
pressing RETURN quickly resumes the interations!!!**

#### Edit: this happens on Windows!

---

Any idea what is happening? :)

Comment: Well, what are you doing in `do_something()`? Could it be waiting on `raw_input` somewhere?

Comment: Operating system and architecture might be useful things to know here. I'd blame Windows :)

Comment: @Spacedman: it is infact running on Windows!! Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you `sys.stdout.flush()` after printing?

Comment: Does the Windows task manager give you any insight when it happens? Any other processes spinning like mad? How sure are you that pressing RETURN quickly is fixing it? Sure its not just coincidence? How long have you tried leaving it alone? Can you stick in some print statements in do_something() to get a better idea of where the halt is?

Comment: @Spacedman task manager gives 0% CPU usage, after pressing RETURN immediately start getting printed out :) they get printed probably 100 a second.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance it is the terminal window (or "dos box", or whatever) that is to blame?

For example, in many terminal windows, if there is a scroll bar, and you are scrolled anywhere but the bottom, it will stay there; thus, it will seem that nothing is happening.  But when you press a key, the terminal window scrolls immediately to the bottom, and you can see the output being printed?

Just a wild guess.